# Censorship of comments

Tags: discussion

In the last few days, the top question on Travel.SE has involved carrying a vibrator through the UAE: [Where to put vibrator when transit flight goes through UAE and dubai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184079/where-to-put-vibrator-when-transit-flight-goes-through-uae-and-dubai)

The OP's somewhat unfortunate choice of the phrase "where should I put it" has led to some gentle ribbing and funny cultural references in the comments: however, all of these appear to have been unceremoniously nuked, not just once but twice.

Really?  If we're so offended by the mildest suggestion that a penetrative sex toy is used for its intended purpose, shouldn't we just delete the entire question?

Comment: remember, comments are not expected to be permanent in any case, they are to aid in improving the question or answer post. Joke comments are low value, and as @Willeke pointed out they may be offensive to some of our audience.

Answer (score 3):

Being a "worldwide site" is just on paper! in reality the western standards of "political correctness" are being enforced even on silly and funny comments.

The accidental comedy in comments --in my opinion-- *used to be* one of the site's main features, now it's vanished.

I wonder if someone wrote "I eat beef burgers" and a Hindu got offended, would the mods take an action and delete the comment? I think not! simply because it does not go against their culture(s) and it seems fine to them, you know, [selective] freedom of speech.

Remember, this is my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

We are a world wide site and what is gentle ribbing and funny cultural references in one culture is beyond good taste in an other.

As I have only nuked them once one of the other mods likely also took action.

As a woman I did feel the suggestion of traveling with the object in the suggested location an insult.

And we do have the tradition not to allow illegal tips, which this also would be, which is a further reason to wipe it.

A sex toy used as intended and only indicated, not described or transported in luggage is within the bounds of the site and as this is not the first question about it likely one that is needed for some people.

Besides, comments can de deleted for many reasons and moderators can not leave a reason other than a new comment to the same post, which I did not feel needed in this case.

Comment: By that logic, shouldn't we ban questions about sex toys, since they're not merely in bad taste but illegal in some countries?

Comment: No, it is only bringing them into countries where they are illegal which is illegal.

Comment: If we as a world wide site shall avoid everything, which is beyond good taste world wide, why do we have a female moderator? Just asking to show the absurdity of avoiding or censoring everything someone somewhere might be offended by.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, is that an insult on purpose or just because you did not think. About 50 percent of our potential users are female so having a female keeping an eye out for what is posted is just common sense. If you want someone who is censoring everything elect someone else next time, as a Dutch person I allow a lot many other nationalities would not